# Get GPU info on Android without SurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpu, surfaceview

On Android, is there a way to get GPU information without creating a SurfaceView? I'm not looking to draw anything using OpenGL, but I just need to get hardware information like vendor, OpenGL ES version, extensions available etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I am not sure how to do that with Android but the function glGetString allows you to access the OpenGL information. Here is a sample C++ style code that will output the extensions supported by your hardware that I hope you'll be able to adapt to Android:

```
void PrettyPrintExtensions(){
    std::string extensions = (const char*) glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
    char* extensionStart = &extensions[0];
    char** extension = &extensionStart;
    std::cout << "Supported OpenGL ES Extensions:" << std::endl;
    while (*extension)
        std::cout << '\t' << strsep(extension, " ") << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

By changing the parameter of glGetString you can also access the Vendor, renderer and version.
Please see:

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glGetString.xml

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, on Android, the function glGetString() is only available from an object of type GL10 (or GL11, GL20 depending on the version you use). You cannot instantiate this object on your own, but it is passed to you as parameters for event listeners (onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) for instance). [OpenGL Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es10.html#projection-and-views)