# Get nothing when retriving OpengGL capabilities values via glget on android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to detect whether those devices running my game support some OpengGL features, like GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS. I had wrote these codes:

```
int[] result = new int[1];

GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, result, 0);
```

I have read the official document and it said the return value must be higher than 8, but what I have got from the result is always 0.
I had used these things via C language on IOS well, but on android they had really confused me.
What should i do to finish this kind of tasks on android?

I have found that "OpenGL Extensions Viewer"(http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/) can detect a lot of things on android and it only has a listview on screen, can I get these informations without create a custom GLSurfaceView and a Renderer?

I found this similar question   [Get GPU info on Android without SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442720/get-gpu-info-on-android-without-surfaceview)  But it also has no best answer.

I have solved this problem now, I put the detecting codes in another Activity, and follow this tutorial http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/ to get an OpenGL ES 2.0 context, then retrieve these capability infos via gl API calls, after all those done, I jump back to my main activity.

Comment: Check for errors via `glGetError`. There must be a valid context around. Effectively, this means -- assuming you use the `GLSurfaceView` -- all calls to GL ES are happen inside the renderer thread.

Comment: I found this similar question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442720/get-gpu-info-on-android-without-surfaceview  But it also has no best answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.anddev.org/android-2d-3d-graphics-opengl-tutorials-f2/possible-to-do-opengl-off-screen-rendering-in-android-t13232.html#wrap). The class creates a new `GL10` instance without any fuzz directly with `EGL`. This should be enough to query the context for capabilities.

What I'd like to know is whether the capabilites depend on the chosen `EGLConfig`...